# RestSharp ExecAsync<T> where T is a nested object

Tags: restsharp

I have a method that calls RestSharp client `ExecuteAsync<T>` where the `T` I am passing is a nested object. I get an exception that says

> InvalidProgramException: Request for the resource
>   /v1/accounts/AN_1476935163870 failed No parameterless constructor
>   defined for this object.

The object I am passing is:

```
public class GetAccountResponse : IGetAccountResponse
    {
        public GetAccountResponseBasicInfo basicInfo { get; set; }
        public GetAccountResponseBillingAndPayment billingAndPayment { get; set; }
        public GetAccountResponseMetrics metrics { get; set; }
        public string billToContact { get; set; }
        public string soldToContact { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }
    }
```

Where the objects for the properties `basicInfo`, `billingAndPayment`, and metrics are classes that have definitions and I have not defined a consturctor. I also have tried replacing the objects with interfaces but it still throws an exception.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible causes of this issue:

- Regression in RestSharp that added the `new` constraint to typed request methods, which was fixed this week
- Serialization issue. In that case, you can try another serializer, we have libraries that support NewtosoftJson, Utf8Json and System.Text.Json in addition to the built-in SimpleJson